# B+ Tree String Keys

Tags: javascript, key-value, b-tree

How do I make a B+ tree in JavaScript for indexing that takes in strings as keys and holds strings as values? I'm doing a search/indexer where each term in a document corresponds to a URI where it is located on a webpage.

EDIT: we are modifying the code located in this repo:
https://github.com/santanubasu/BPlusJS

Comment: could you add an example?

Comment: Please provide what you have attempted so far